# how to import file using macro into a new sheet within a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I basically have this code which brings in a csv file manually and places it in a sheet that is established called TEST.  I need it to be imported into a new sheet that it creates automiatically within the workbook.  Here is the code....

```
Sub load_csv()
    Dim fStr As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'fStr is the file path and name of the file you selected.
        fStr = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & fStr, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST").Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "CAPTURE"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With
End Sub
```

answers greatfully recieved I am sure it is easy enough but can't find an answer online and reference book hence why i am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Worksheet from your workbook and use it to copy your CSV file:

```
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
NewSheet.Name = "NewSheet"

With NewSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & fStr, Destination:=NewSheet.Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "CAPTURE"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
```